# beautifulsoup delete elements other than required element in xml tree

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am using `beautifulsoup` to delete an element from `xml` document. It is deleting required tag but also removing some other info from `xml` document which is not related to that element. How to stop this?

**Code to reproduce:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text_file = open('C:\Ashok\sample.xml', 'r')
s = text_file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'xml')
u = soup.find('Version', text='29.2.3')
fed = u.findParent()

fed.decompose()

f = open('C:\Ashok\sample.xml', "w")

f.write(str(soup))
f.close()
```

Find comparison attached. deleted other info showed in red rectangles.

[image]

It is updating Header and footer tags which I did not ask code to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What happens?

The empty elements are not deleted only notation is transformed.

#### Empty elements in `XML`

An `element` with no content is empty and in `XML`, you can indicate an empty element like this:

```
<element></element>
```

An alternativ notation is the so called self-closing tag:

```
<element />
```

Both forms have identical results in `XML` readers, parsers,...